# Chaining method calls

Tags: dart

According to [official Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/cheatsheet#chaining-method-calls), it is mentioned that:

> Chaining method calls
>
> ```
> a..b = true..c = 5;
> ```
>
> Cascade used for chaining access to methods and other members.
> Equivalent:
>
> ```
> a.b = true; a.c = 5;
> ```

Can someone explain the meaning of the above lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `user` as an instace of following class:

```
class User {
  int age;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
}
```

Now you can update data in `user` as following:

```
user.age = 5;
user.firstName = 'John';
user.lastName = 'Doe';
```

but if you use chaining access as described in the documentation.
Then it will look something like this:

```
user..age = 5
    ..firstName = 'John'
    ..lastName = 'Doe';
```

Note: sequence of assignment of the properties does not matter, but it might be of importance while calling functions or methods like this.

Just a simple & random example:

```
painter..computeLayout()
    ..initializePaint()
    ..render();
```

above is same as:

```
painter.computeLayout();
painter.initializePaint();
painter.render();
```

in the above example all of the methods were called on `painter` object/instance but the sequence here must be followed as without paint or layout the render will not work.

Comment: Nice answer.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Cascades**

To perform a sequence of operations on the same object, use cascades (..). We’ve all seen an expression like this:

```
myObject.someMethod()
```

It invokes `someMethod()` on `myObject`, and the result of the expression is the return value of `someMethod()`.

Here’s the same expression with a cascade:

```
myObject..someMethod()
```

Although it still invokes `someMethod()` on `myObject`, the result of the expression isn’t the return value — it’s a reference to `myObject`! Using cascades, you can chain together operations that would otherwise require separate statements. For example, consider this code:

```
var button = querySelector('#confirm');
button.text = 'Confirm';
button.classes.add('important');
button.onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'));
```

With cascades, the code becomes much shorter, and you don’t need the button variable:

```
querySelector('#confirm')
..text = 'Confirm'
..classes.add('important')
..onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'));
```